# "npm install" doesn't installs all depencies

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am building a production code of React using npm. 
`npm install` doesn't install all dependencies.
It always shows some warnings all the time

```
>npm install
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@3.0.8 requires a peer of eslint@5.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN acorn-jsx@5.0.1 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2 requires a peer of webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@2.11.5 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package react is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package react-dom is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 68747 packages in 99.074s
found 114 vulnerabilities (104 low, 9 moderate, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I have tried installing the dependencies manually but their different versions appear the other time.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-pivottable",
  "version": "0.8.0",
  "description": "An Excel like pivot table",
  "main": "PivotTableUI.js",
  "files": [
    "PivotTable.js",
    "PivotTableUI.js",
    "PlotlyRenderers.js",
    "TableRenderers.js",
    "Utilities.js",
    "PivotTable.js.map",
    "PivotTableUI.js.map",
    "PlotlyRenderers.js.map",
    "TableRenderers.js.map",
    "Utilities.js.map",
    "pivottable.css"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/805bluebell/frontEndProjProd.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "pivottable"
  ],
  "author": "Pankaj Kumar",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/805bluebell/frontEndProjProd/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://805bluebell.github.io/frontEndProjProd",
  "dependencies": {
    "acorn": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.3.1",
    "plotly.js": "^1.47.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-draggable": "^3.0.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "react-sortablejs": "^1.3.4",
    "sortablejs": "^1.6.1",
    "typescript": "^3.4.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=15.0.0",
    "react-dom": ">=15.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "eslint": "^4.5.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.3.0",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "papaparse": "^4.3.6",
    "prettier": "^1.8.2",
    "react": ">=15.0.0",
    "react-dom": ">=15.0.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "react-plotly.js": "^2.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "webpack": "^4.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.3"
  }
}
```

I want to make a production build to deploy.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the expected results?

Comment: I can't do "npm start" and "npm build" to run & deploy my app. They all throw the above error.

Answer (score -1):

you should try yarn:

- delete package-lock.json file
- delete node-modules folder
- $yarn install